# What is the canonical way to get string representation of an error in typescript

Tags: typescript, tslint

With [`useUnknownInCatchVariables`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41013) enabled (default in typescript 4.4 strict mode) what is the canonical way of getting a string representation of an error. Until typescript 4.4 `error` was given type `any` and we have never seen a case where `toString()` was not defined (though I understand that in principle it can happen).

```
try {
    ...
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error) // OK
    const errStr = error.toString() // Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
}
```

I assume this is a very common use case.

Casting to `any` gives `tslint` warnings, so that is not an attractive solution.

I could of course make some function to convert `unknown` into `string`, but doesn't seem reasonable that everyone needs to do that.

Comment: `const errStr = \`${error}\`;`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thanks. Will definitely do the trick. I sugggest you post as answer. (In principle I don't understand why I am allowed to do that, but not call toString() ? )

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jonrsharpe for this suggestion. (Since he did not post as answer I will do so):

```
const errStr = `${error}`
```